# asyncData and fetch is not setting data

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt v2.14.1 with typescript and **`nuxt-property-decorator`** package.
I am facing lots of issues.

1. I am not able to set data from fetch() or asyncData.

   ```
   console.log(this.fruits) // => undefined
   console.log(response.data);//  => [{},..}
   this.fruits = response.data; // => this does not set fruits
   ```

Vue dev tools show fruits as an empty array too.

Can anyone help me understand what's happening and how to solve it?

Here is the code using fetch:

```
@Component({
  layout: 'AppLayout',
  async fetch({ query, store }: Context) {
    const self = this;
    const model = new Car();
    model.setFilters(query);
    const response = await model.$api.$get('/new/cars').catch(() => {
      store.$showError('Unable to fetch cars');
    });
    if (response) {
      // @ts-ignore
      self.cars = Car.collect(response.data as Partial<Car>[]);
    }
  },
})
export default class index extends Vue {
  cars: Car[] = [];
}
```

The above code works if I just rename **`fetch`** to **`mounted`**.

Also, when using asyncData, the code seems to work, and I see my car list, and then, when page loading completes, page autmatically becomes empty even though I can see cars listed in Vue dev tools.

**Update: Not using nuxt context in fetch parameter seems to work.**
No idea why though.

Comment: You haven't posted enough to say but your problem is almost certainly that you're trying to access the data before it's actually set. Don't forget that objects logged to the console are a *live view of the object*, not a snapshot of the object at the time it got logged. It can give you a false impression of what happens when.

Comment: Within asyncData you will not have access to`this`, however you can access it within fetch. Could you please add more code/details on errors!!!

Comment: @HardikShah Thanks for your time. Updated the code.

Comment: Same here, i can not resolve this. console.log is ok but data are not shown on view.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried by just returning an object?

```
  async fetch({ query, store }: Context) {
    const model = new Car();
    model.setFilters(query);
    const response = await model.$api.$get('/new/cars').catch(() => {
      store.$showError('Unable to fetch cars');
    });
    if (response) {
      return {
         cars: Car.collect(response.data as Partial<Car>[])
      }
    }
  },
```

By just returning it it should merge your return object with your data object.

They wrote it also in the docs: https://nuxtjs.org/api/

> The result from asyncData will be merged with data.

Note here: Since `asyncData()` happens on the server side it doesnt have access to the vue instance with `this`

> Warning: You don't have access to the component instance through `this`
> inside asyncData because it is called before initiating the component.

Comment: Does that work in fetch? I'll try and let you know.

Comment: No, returning object from fetch did not work for me.

Comment: @priosshrsth and asyncdata?

Comment: returning object from asyncData do set cars, and I can see it in vue dev tools, but, template is not rendered. Actually, it appears for a second, and I can see my car lists with image, and then it goes away, and  the page becomes empty.

Comment: Did we get any answer for this?